# Reverting edited question to original

Tags: support, suggested-edits, edits, rollbacks

I made an edit to a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20672331/accessing-private-methods-from-another-class) but after I submitted it, I discovered that although the user intended to say `method` instead of `variable`, the answers and comments were correct regarding the question as is and my edit made all the answers (including mine) look out of place.

Any one reading the question now would wonder why the answers were saying something completely different to what the user asked. I think it would make more sense to change the question to what it was before the edit. Is is possible?

Comment: users with over 2K rep can rollback in one click (I just did that for you). Since you have less rep, your option would be to suggest a next edit reverting prior changes. For that reverting edit, you better write an edit summary explaining the prior mistake

Comment: Okay.Good to know such feature exists.Thanks